# In VBA/ADO creating a rs field based on concatenating field values from many records

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I have an MDB table with 2 fields:

```
+-------------+------------------+
| salesperson | Transaction_Date |
+-------------+------------------+
| John        | 12/11/2018       |
| John        | 13/11/2018       |
| John        | 18/11/2018       |
| Steeve      | 23/12/2018       |
| Steeve      | 29/12/2018       |
+-------------+------------------+
```

In VBA (in Excel) I want through ADO to create the  following format:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------+
| salesperson |  Transaction_Date_Concatenated   |
+-------------+----------------------------------+
| John        | 12/11/2018-13/11/2018-18/11/2018 |
| Steeve      | 23/12/2018-29/12/2018            |
+-------------+----------------------------------+
```

The number of `Transaction_Dates` for each salesperson may vary from 1 to 30.

The following SQL creates a record for each salesperson but it doesn't, of course, produces the concatenated field although it looks as in the direction of what I want

```
SQL = " SELECT SalesPerson, max(Date)  as value1  FROM 0TargetTemplate   GROUP BY SalesPerson"
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this cannot be achieved using SQL alone. You'll need to use a VBA function to iterate over the records and construct the delimited string.

Allen Browne has created an existing example which may be found [here](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

For your particular task, you might call the function in the following manner:

```sql
select
    [0TargetTemplate].SalesPerson, 
    ConcatRelated
    (
        "[0TargetTemplate].Transaction_Date", 
        "[0TargetTemplate]", 
        "[0TargetTemplate].SalesPerson = '" & [0TargetTemplate].SalesPerson & "'",
        "[0TargetTemplate].Transaction_Date",
        "-"
    ) as Transaction_Date_Concatenated
from
    [0TargetTemplate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggested code and function from the [link](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) I wrote a procedure in VBA Access but get an error "Too few parameters" in the *Set rs=* statement. I've tried in VBA EXCEL with proper connections but get an error about "**ConcatRelated**" function not recognized, although properly referenced in a VBA module

```
Sub test()
SQL = "SELECT [tblOrders].CompanyName, ConcatRelated ('[tblOrders].Transaction_Date',[tblOrders], [tblOrders].SalesPerson =' [tblOrders].SalesPerson', [tblOrders].Transaction_Date) AS Transaction_Date_Concatenated FROM tblOrders;"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
 On Error GoTo resultsetError
 dbValue = rs!Variable
 MsgBox dbValue, vbOKOnly, "RS VALUE"
resultsetError:
 MsgBox "Error Retrieving value from database", vbOKOnly, "Database Error"

End Sub
```